# implode invalid arguments

Tags: php, implode

```
function delete($rowid) 
{
   $rowids = implode(", ",$rowid);
   $sql = "DELETE FROM pms WHERE id IN (".$rowids.")";
   print $sql;
}

if (isset($_POST['submit']))  
{
    delete($rowid);
}

?>

<form method="post" action="test.php">

<input type="checkbox" name="rowid[]" value="1771367" /><br >
<input type="checkbox" name="rowid[]" value="345342" /><br >
<input type="checkbox" name="rowid[]" value="572347" /><br >
<input type="checkbox" name="rowid[]" value="902358" /><br >
<input type="checkbox" name="rowid[]" value="234654" /><br ><br >

<input type="submit" name="submit" />

</form>
```

> Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed in
>   C:\pub\test.php on line 4 DELETE FROM pms WHERE id IN ()

What Am I doing wrong here? Going crazy over here..

Comment: Did you try `$_POST['rowid']`?

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `$_POST['rowid']`, if you're grabbing that from post.

Also:

**Sanitize your SQL!**

Comment: Someone's going to submit your form with <input type="checkbox" name="rowid[]" value="SELECT id FROM pms" />.

Answer (score 0):

You're not passing the right variable to your function. You need to call it with

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))  
{
    delete($_POST['rowid']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like you read some really old PHP manual where `register_globals = on` , you need to read the POST parameters in your case..

```
function delete($rowid) 
{
   $rowids = implode(", ",$rowid);
   $sql = "DELETE FROM pms WHERE id IN (".$rowids.")";
   print $sql;
}

if (isset($_POST['submit']))  
{
        delete($_POST['rowid']);
}
```